# View Pager circular indicator to custom View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using this [Vertical View Pager](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager) in one of my app. This view pager scrolls vertically instead of traditional view pager which scrolls horizontally.

I want to show View Pager indicator in this View Pager. I came across this [View Pager Indicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) library to show indicator to the view pager.

Below is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/view_pager_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip" />

            <fr.castorflex.android.verticalviewpager.VerticalViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Below is my activity code to attach view pager with the view pager indicator

```
mViewPager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
mViewPagerIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_indicator);
mViewPagerIndicator.setViewPager(mVerticalViewPager); //need to pass the object of support v4 ViewPager
```

The third line in the above code gives error. This is because the setViewPager() method takes `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` as parameter and I am sending object of VerticalViewPager.

How can I send the Object this CustomViewPager? How can I view pager indicator to this CustomViewPager?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I have [adapted (forked)](https://github.com/BrantApps/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/library/src/com/brantapps/viewpagerindicator) Jake Wharton's `ViewPagerIndicator` library to permit vertical and horizontal view paging (with indicator) as can be seen in my application's listing [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oceanlife&hl=en).

My forked library found [here](https://github.com/BrantApps/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/) will achieve the effect you require.